# How to Deploy React App on my own Server Or Domain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I made a React App and It works fine on my local server and I was trying to Deploying App on my Domain but it doesn't work at all.
Its good to know that I have server that connected to my domain and my react app is working fine on my server too but not showing anything in my domain.
[image: dont worry about warnings]

and this is my dependencies
`"dependencies": { "@apollo/client": "^3.1.3", "apollo-graphql": "^0.5.0", "apollo-server-express": "^1.3.6", "bcrypt": "^5.0.0", "body-parser": "^1.18.3", "concurrently": "^3.5.1", "cors": "^2.8.4", "dotenv": "^5.0.1", "express": "^4.17.1", "graphql": "^0.13.2", "graphql-tools": "^3.0.2", "graphql-type-long": "^0.1.1", "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1", "mongodb-core": "^3.2.7", "mongoose": "^5.1.3", "react-images-upload": "^1.2.8", "react-persian": "^1.1.1", "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0" },`

one more thing
I am using Transmit to upload file in my server and my react app is on react-recipes file
[image: Transmit]

// edit
I build the application and there is Build folder
where should I upload it and What should I do????

Comment: 1. Is your react app built before deploying it to your server?
2. You need to point your server to place where your `index.html` file is.

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk build it now, now what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

ok,I build the app and instead of using server,try use cPanel and it work fine,just upload all fiels that are inside build folder and you are good to go